# How do I see and customize the source code to Python's defined functions; describe, skew, and kurtosis definitions?

Tags: python, function

I want to see and customize the python defined functions; describe, skew, and kurtosis.  I can't seem to find how to access these functions codes though. I am using Jupyter Lab. Thank you for any help.

Comment: these are not standard library functions. what library are you referring to? if they are form an open-source library... well... have a look at the source.

Comment: `help()` will show the information about what the function does and what parameters to be passed. But I don't think you can edit defined functions. May be you can override them with your own implementation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Thank you each. I will try each of these suggestions and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're talking about SciPy functions. Here are the definitions: [`describe`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/stats.py#L1291), [`skew`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/stats.py#L1070), [`kurtosis`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/stats.py#L1173). I found them via the [SciPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kurtosis.html) -- the `[source]` button. You can customize them by copying the code and changing it in your own module.

Comment: I saw these definitions, though somehow missed the code at the end of each after each example section.  I will try modifying these codes to see what I can do and report back.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Result; Scipy's stats.describe(DataFrame) does include skew and kurtosis, but not my 25%,50%,75% interquartiles and is not in columns.

Pandas's DataFrame.describe(include='all') includes interquartiles, but not skew and kurtosis and is in columns, so I would like to edit Panda's describe source code to add skew and kurtosis.

When I try to test panda's describe source code as def DescribeSK before trying to add skew and kurtosis code, then use DataFrame.DescribeSK(include='all'), I get;

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DescribeSK'.  Any ideas why?

Comment: My pandas .describe() does give me summary stats not including skew and kurtosis and references this as the source code, but I can't find this specific code file to try altering the def describe; "~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py".  Any ideas where I can find this exact file that seems to be functioning well?

Comment: I did compare scipy and pandas describe and found these differences;

Comment: Scipy's stats.describe(DataFrame) does include skew and kurtosis, but not my 25%,50%,75% interquartiles and is not in columns.

Comment: Pandas's DataFrame.describe(include='all') includes interquartiles, but not skew and kurtosis and is in columns, so I would like to edit Panda's describe source code to add skew and kurtosis.

Comment: So, I would like to add skew and kurtosis to the actual working pandas describe source code known as "~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", but I can't find this actual file anywhere.  The pandas describe source code that I do find can't seem to run without error.  See links in answer below.  I wanted to take this source code, test it as is to be sure it works, then simply change the def describeSK name and call it with DataFrame.describeSK() to confirm a 2nd time that my code is pulling from my modified def.  Then try adding skew and kurtosis.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED NOW;
1- I checked the notes of describe() to see exactly which file was source.  Apparently there are several generic.py files, so this is important.

Fist, I saved the file before any changes as genericBACKUP.py to be safe.

Then each small change to code, I edited the notes with a simple #1, 2, 3 to confirm I was loading the version of file with newest changes that I intended. Note that both terminal and jupyter needed restarting to force the newest saved file with defs to load.

1st - copy entire code of def describe and past it below itself.

2nd - add "SK" onto "def describeSK" to include skew & kurtosis.

3rd - add skew & kurtosis like this to the new def describeSK section;

```
    def describe_numeric_1d(series):
        stat_index = (
            ["count", "mean", "std", "min"] + formatted_percentiles + ["max", "skew", "kurt"]
        )
        d = (
            [series.count(), series.mean(), series.std(), series.min()]
            + series.quantile(percentiles).tolist()
            + [series.max(), series.skew(), series.kurt()]
        )
        return pd.Series(d, index=stat_index, name=series.name)
```

My describeSK() output looks like this now. Perfect!

[describeSK() output example link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIiyx.png)